# Get Index from a button on ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn>
             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                      <Button 
                          Width="18" 
                          Height="18" 
                          Background="Transparent"
                          BorderThickness="0"
                          Click="OnMapItemSettingClick">
                          <Image 
                              Source="settings.png"
                              Width="16"
                              Height="16"/>
                      </Button>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
```

I had a ListView and each item has a button on it. Just wondering how do i get index number of this list item when i click the button on it?

Comment: If you have bound the ListView's ItemsSource to a collection of objects, you may pass the Button's DataContext to the IndexOf method of the collection.

Comment: @Clemens I define my button in a Template, and ListViewItem has been added in dynamically, not sure how to bind source with 'objects'...

Comment: What exactly would the "index number" be?  Do you mean it's order in the underlying list of ListViewItems?

Comment: @DonBoitnott yes!

Comment: Binding the ListView's ItemsSource means this: `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" ...>` where ItemCollection is a collection property in the DataContext of the ListView (the view model). This is how any ItemsControl should be used. Adding objects to its Items property in code behind is bad practice. It's also unclear why you want to get the index at all.

Comment: @Clemens That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to found the item, and after that get its index.

First of all, name the ListView, let's say 'myListView' and after that use the DataContext to find the item:

```
private void OnMapItemSettingClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

    int index = myListView.Items.IndexOf(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos! I just tried this but the item is found as null.